# Jquery resizable for children

Tags: jquery, resizable

In my project,dynamically controls are being added in html. Controls are all wrapped in  element. 
resizable is implemented on div. But children contained in div are not getting resized. 
I dont have fixed ids for children nor classes,so how can this behavior be implemented. 
As alsoResize requires fix ids.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `alsoResize :'li'` or whatever are the tags of the children , not to sure but i think u might getaway with `:children` worth a shot :)

Comment: I have used class for div children where width,height is 100%,but in case of more than 1 children it is not working properly.